# ASp.NET MVC2 - Rendering an action link and text on same line

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I will like to achieve the following html using Html.ActionLink:

```
<li><a href="/WhatWeDo/JohnDoe">John Doe</a>President</li>
```

The name "John Doe" and title "President" will be coming from a staff model.  This is what I have:

```
 <% foreach (var item in Model as IEnumerable<AkwiMemorial.Models.Staff>)
 { %>    
 <li><%= Html.ActionLink(item.Name, "GetStaffDetails", "WhatWeDo", new { staffID = item.Id }, null) %> item.Position</li>   
<% } %>
```

Instead of rendering "item.Position" literally, I will like this string extracted from the model.

TIA.

Comment: `<%= item.Position %>` should do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<% foreach (var item in Model as IEnumerable<AkwiMemorial.Models.Staff>)
 { %>    
 <li>
    <%= Html.ActionLink(item.Name, "GetStaffDetails", "WhatWeDo", new { staffID = item.Id }, null) %> 
    <%=item.Position%>
 </li>   
<% } %>
```